# how can opencl local memory size works?

Tags: image-processing, opencl, gpu

I use opencl for image processing. For example, I have one 1000*800 image.

I use a 2D global size as 1000*800, and the local work size is 10*8.

In that case, will the GPU give 100*100 computing units automatic?

And do these 10000 units works at the same time so it can be parallel?

If the hardware has no 10000 units, will one units do the same thing for more than one time?

I tested the local size, I found if we use a very small size (1*1) or a big size(100*80), they are both very slow, but if we use a middle value(10*8) it is faster. So last question, Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work group sizes can be a tricky concept to grasp.

If you are just getting started and you don't need to share information *between* work items, ignore local work size and leave it NULL. The runtime will pick one itself.

Hardcoding a local work size of 10*8 is wasteful and won't utilize the hardware well. Some hardware, for example, prefers work group sizes that are multiples of 32.

OpenCL doesn't specify what order the work will be done it, just that it will be done. It might do one work group at a time, or it may do them in groups, or (for small global sizes) all of them together. You don't know and you can't control it.

To your question "why?": the hardware may run work groups in SIMD (single instruction multiple data) and/or in "Wavefronts" (AMD) or "Warps" (NVIDIA). Too small of a work group size won't leverage the hardware well. Too large and your registers may spill to global memory (slow). "Just right" will run fastest, but it is hard to pick this without benchmarking. So for now, leave it NULL and let the runtime pick for you. Later, when you become an OpenCL expert and understand more about how the hardware works, you can try specifying the work group size. However, be aware that the optimal size may be different for different hardware, and there are other rules (like global size must be a multiple of local size).